# Como fazer um spinner puro em css?

Tags: css, css3

É possível fazer um spinner com CSS puro, sem Javascript ?

```
<div class="main spinner"> O que é Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker </div>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Existem diversas formas de você fazer, abaixo demostrei quatro tipos diferentes de spinner que retirei das seguintes fontes:

- [Only CSS loadings spinner](https://stephanwagner.me/only-css-loading-spinner)
- [Spinkit](http://tobiasahlin.com/spinkit/)
- [CSS only loaders](https://www.pexels.com/blog/css-only-loaders/)

**Exemplo 1:**

```css
/* Spinner CSS */
@keyframes spinner {
  to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
.spinner:before {
  content: '';
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 20%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-top-color: #333;
  animation: spinner .6s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="spinner"></div>
```

**Exemplo 2:**

```css
.spinner {
  margin: 100px auto;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.spinner > div {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 100%;
  width: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  
  -webkit-animation: sk-stretchdelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: sk-stretchdelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.spinner .rect2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.1s;
  animation-delay: -1.1s;
}

.spinner .rect3 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.0s;
  animation-delay: -1.0s;
}

.spinner .rect4 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.9s;
  animation-delay: -0.9s;
}

.spinner .rect5 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.8s;
  animation-delay: -0.8s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes sk-stretchdelay {
  0%, 40%, 100% { -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.4) }  
  20% { -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.0) }
}

@keyframes sk-stretchdelay {
  0%, 40%, 100% { 
    transform: scaleY(0.4);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.4);
  }  20% { 
    transform: scaleY(1.0);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="spinner">
  <div class="rect1"></div>
  <div class="rect2"></div>
  <div class="rect3"></div>
  <div class="rect4"></div>
  <div class="rect5"></div>
</div>
```

**Exemplo 3:**

```css
.spinner {
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  width: 70px;
  text-align: center;
}

.spinner > div {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  background-color: #333;

  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-animation: sk-bouncedelay 1.4s infinite ease-in-out both;
  animation: sk-bouncedelay 1.4s infinite ease-in-out both;
}

.spinner .bounce1 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.32s;
  animation-delay: -0.32s;
}

.spinner .bounce2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.16s;
  animation-delay: -0.16s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes sk-bouncedelay {
  0%, 80%, 100% { -webkit-transform: scale(0) }
  40% { -webkit-transform: scale(1.0) }
}

@keyframes sk-bouncedelay {
  0%, 80%, 100% { 
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
  } 40% { 
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
    transform: scale(1.0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="spinner">
  <div class="bounce1"></div>
  <div class="bounce2"></div>
  <div class="bounce3"></div>
</div>
```

**Exemplo 4:**

```css
.spinner {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  margin: 80px;
  border: 0px solid #27ae60;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 -20px 0 24px #27ae60 inset;
  animation: rotate 1s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="spinner"></div>
```

Answer (score 10):

Uma outra técnica para fazer esse *loaders* ou *spinners* de carregamento é usar SVG Animado.

Primeiro é preciso deixar claro que vc pode por exemplo ter um SVG onde vc vai animar os seus vetores usando propriedades do CSS como `transform`, `opacite`, etc, tudo pelo CSS. Ou vc pode animar tudo diretamente dentro do SVG usado as tag nativas dele como `<animate>`, `<set>` e `<animateMotion>` por exemplo.

Aqui temos um exemplo de animação 100% feita com CSS usando `@keyframes,` porém animando a propriedade `stroke-dashoffset` do SVG. **Dica:** Nessa outra resposta tem mais dentalhes sobre o `stroke-dasharray` e `strok-dashoffset` para animar o "contorno" de um elemento HTML [Pintar parcialmente a borda em css](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/348883/pintar-parcialmente-a-borda-em-css/348906#348906)

Repare que eu deixei um Triangulo com a animação, e o outro eu deixe apenas o SVG simples, sem a animação do CSS.

```css
html, body {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}

#triangle {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 65%;
          transform-origin: 50% 65%;
}

#triangle polygon {
  stroke-dasharray: 17;
  -webkit-animation: dash 2.5s cubic-bezier(0.35, 0.04, 0.63, 0.95) infinite;
          animation: dash 2.5s cubic-bezier(0.35, 0.04, 0.63, 0.95) infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 136;
  }
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 136;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="triangle" width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="-3 -4 39 39">
  <polygon fill="#EFEFEF" stroke="#333333" stroke-width="1" points="16,0 32,32 0,32"></polygon>
</svg>

<svg id="" width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="-3 -4 39 39">
  <polygon fill="#EFEFEF" stroke="#333333" stroke-width="1" points="16,0 32,32 0,32"></polygon>
</svg>
```

*Fonte:* https://codepen.io/dominickolbe/pen/YXYyvW

---

**Animação Nativa com o SVG**

Aqui tem um guia que pode te ajudar caso queira anima tudo diretamente dentro do SVG https://css-tricks.com/guide-svg-animations-smil/

Exemplo de SVG animado nativamente, repare que não tem CSS e tudo foi animado dentro do próprio SVG:

```html
<svg version="1.1" width="320" height="320" viewBox="0 0 320 320" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <path id="r1">
      <animate id="p1" attributeName="d" values="m160,160l0,0 0,0;m130,110l30,-17 30,17;m130,60l30,-17 30,17;m160,20l0,0 0,0" dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
      <animate attributeName="stroke-width" values="0;4;4;4;0" dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="p1.begin"/>
    </path>
    <path id="r2">
      <animate attributeName="d" values="m160,160l0,0 0,0;m130,110l30,-17 30,17;m130,60l30,-17 30,17;m160,20l0,0 0,0" dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="p1.begin+1s"/>
      <animate attributeName="stroke-width" values="0;4;4;4;0" dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="p1.begin+1s"/>
    </path>
    <path id="r3">
      <animate attributeName="d" values="m160,160l0,0 0,0;m130,110l30,-17 30,17;m130,60l30,-17 30,17;m160,20l0,0 0,0" dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="p1.begin+2s"/>
      <animate attributeName="stroke-width" values="0;4;4;4;0" dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="p1.begin+2s"/>
    </path>
    <path id="r4">
      <animate id="p1" attributeName="d" values="m160,160l0,0 0,0;m130,110l30,-17 30,17;m130,60l30,-17 30,17;m160,20l0,0 0,0" dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="p1.begin+3s"/>
      <animate attributeName="stroke-width" values="0;4;4;4;0" dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="p1.begin+3s"/>
    </path>
    <path id="r5">
      <animate attributeName="d" values="m160,160l0,0 0,0;m130,110l30,-17 30,17;m130,60l30,-17 30,17;m160,20l0,0 0,0" dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="p1.begin+4s"/>
      <animate attributeName="stroke-width" values="0;4;4;4;0" dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="p1.begin+4s"/>
    </path>
    <path id="r6">
      <animate attributeName="d" values="m160,160l0,0 0,0;m130,110l30,-17 30,17;m130,60l30,-17 30,17;m160,20l0,0 0,0" dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="p1.begin+5s"/>
      <animate attributeName="stroke-width" values="0;4;4;4;0" dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="p1.begin+5s"/>
    </path>
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#r1"/>
  <use xlink:href="#r1" transform="rotate(60 160 160)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#r1" transform="rotate(120 160 160)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#r1" transform="rotate(180 160 160)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#r1" transform="rotate(240 160 160)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#r1" transform="rotate(300 160 160)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#r2" transform="rotate(30 160 160)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#r2" transform="rotate(90 160 160)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#r2" transform="rotate(150 160 160)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#r2" transform="rotate(210 160 160)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#r2" transform="rotate(270 160 160)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#r2" transform="rotate(330 160 160)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#r3"/>
  <use xlink:href="#r3" transform="rotate(60 160 160)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#r3" transform="rotate(120 160 160)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#r3" transform="rotate(180 160 160)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#r3" transform="rotate(240 160 160)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#r3" transform="rotate(300 160 160)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#r4" transform="rotate(30 160 160)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#r4" transform="rotate(90 160 160)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#r4" transform="rotate(150 160 160)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#r4" transform="rotate(210 160 160)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#r4" transform="rotate(270 160 160)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#r4" transform="rotate(330 160 160)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#r5"/>
  <use xlink:href="#r5" transform="rotate(60 160 160)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#r5" transform="rotate(120 160 160)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#r5" transform="rotate(180 160 160)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#r5" transform="rotate(240 160 160)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#r5" transform="rotate(300 160 160)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#r6" transform="rotate(30 160 160)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#r6" transform="rotate(90 160 160)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#r6" transform="rotate(150 160 160)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#r6" transform="rotate(210 160 160)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#r6" transform="rotate(270 160 160)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#r6" transform="rotate(330 160 160)"/>
</svg>
```

Aqui tem a documentação oficial W3C sobre animação de SVGs https://svgwg.org/specs/animations/

---

**OBS:**

Vc não precisa de nenhum recurso extra para animar SVGs mas caso deseje existem softwares e APIs que te ajudam a animar e exportar seu SVG animado! Uma opção de plataforma para animar seu SVG online é o https://www.svgator.com/ ou o https://maxwellito.github.io/vivus-instant/

Existem também Frameworks JS para animar SVGs como o http://snapsvg.io/ ou o https://svgjs.com/animating/ e o mais famoso TweenMax GSAP https://greensock.com/svg-tips

Comment: Obrigado, muito bom

Answer (score 6):

A estratégia que usamos é pegar um quadrado, arredondar as bordas com border-radius 50%, pintar as bordas com uma cor transparent ou igual ao fundo, depois você pinta apenas um pedaço da borda da cor que você quer e então coloca esse pedaço de borda pra girar com um animation baseado no transform rotate. :)

```css
.load-spin:before {
  content: '';
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 4px solid white;
  border-top-color: red;
  -webkit-animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
  left: calc(50% - 1.5rem);
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0%  {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
  100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}   
}
```

```html
<div class="load-spin"></div>
```