# Movimento Cadeia de Formigas

Tags: javascript, html, css

estou com uma pulga atrás da orelha e queria saber se vcs poderiam me ajudar nessa.

Estou tentando fazer com que a borda (dashed) de uma div (por exemplo) fique girando no sentido horário como se fosse uma cadeia de formigas indo atrás da outra, em um movimento que seguiria as dimensões da div, só que acabei fazendo um ponteiro e falhei miseravelmente, tem como eu fazer isso que estou querendo, apenas com HTML, CSS e JS?

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

p {
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px dashed white;
  display: inline;
  transition: 0.5s;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

p:hover {
  color: black;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 2px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p id="name">N0V4</p>
</body>
```

Tentei fazer algo com a @keywords spin, porém fiz um ponteiro, e n era esse o resultado que eu estava esperando...

[image: esse é o exemplo de imagem que desejo]

Comment: Mostre o que tentou, se possível, adicione uma imagem do que você deseja

Comment: Pronto é assim que espero

Answer (score 4):

Tem uma forma de fazer, mas para fazer com `border-radius` vai dar mais trabalho, pq vc vai ter que ter um `path` exclusivo dentro do `SVG` ou então usar a propriedade `rx` do `rect` para, mas se vc quiser um retângulo simples esse ou um círculo simples essa reposta vai te ajudar *(no caso do path recomendo que faça no Figma ou outro software que gere o código do SVG de forma automática)*.

Aqui basicamente eu defini um tamanho de `dash` e um `dash-offset`, onde o `dash` é o tracinho e o `dash-offset` é o espaço entre um tracinho e outro. Depois com um `@keyframes` eu fiz a animação mudando o `offset` e dando a impressão que está se movendo.

Como base usei essas outras duas respostas que eu mesmo já tinha dado aqui. Recomendo que leia!!

[Pintar parcialmente a borda em css](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/348883/pintar-parcialmente-a-borda-em-css/348906#348906)

[Como fazer um spinner puro em css?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/296506/como-fazer-um-spinner-puro-em-css/341189#341189)

Sobre a sua resposta, veja o exemplo *(não que extender o CSS mas vc pode ajustar o `dash` e `offset` ao seu gosto etc)*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da imagem acima. Repare que no `@keyframes` quanto maior o valor do `offset` mais rápido fica a animação

```css
.btn {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  transition: 1.5s;
  position: relative;
}
svg,
svg rect,
svg circle{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  fill: transparent;
}
a svg rect,
a svg circle {
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-width: 4;
  transition: all 500ms;
  stroke-dasharray: 10;
  animation: dash 2.5s linear infinite;
}


@keyframes dash {
  to {
    /* quanto maior o valor do offset mais rápido fica a animação */
    stroke-dashoffset: 100;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn">
  <svg>
    <rect></rect>
  </svg>
  Btn
</a>


<a href="#" class="btn" style="height: 100px">
  <svg>
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" />
  </svg>
  Btn
</a>
```

Comment: Acho essa é a maneira certa. Eu conheço outra técnica usando `linear-gradiente` como `background` mas estou hesitante em apresentar pois tenho medo de parecer *gambiarristico*.

Comment: @AugustoVasques hahaha nada disso, CSS eh uma gambiarra por definição praticamente rss. Manda bala ai, eu tinha chegado a pensar nessa hipótese tbm, gradiente e bg-position em dois pseudo elemento 2px maior que o container